# Does "While-Clicking" event handler exist in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, ontouchlistener

I want to call a function while the user is pressing on a button, as an infinite loop as long as the button is pressed, then break once the user releases the button. I can say I am looking for a Button-While-Clicking event handler

I am sure that such an event handler exists in maybe most IDEs. 
How can I approach that in Android Studio?

Providing an example for this sample task is highly appreciated:

While-Clicking:

```
    // Button Clicking
    int i = 0;
    Btn.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TextOne.setText("Clicking" + i++);
                }//onClick
            }//onClickListener
    );//setOnClickListener
```

When released:

```
    // Button Released
    Btn.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TextOne.setText("Released");
                }//onClick
            }//onClickListener
    );//setOnClickListener
```

..

**Edit:**
**Solution** seemed to be the OnTouchListener() event handler and I had to import android.view.MotionEvent; to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for onTouchListener -

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    //Button pressed  
                    TextOne.setText("Clicking");       
                    return true;
                } 
                else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    //Button released
                    TextOne.setText("Released");
                    return true;
                 }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN is generated when the user touches the button and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is generated when the user removes his touch from the button.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Jyotman I will try it right away then mark as an answer and maybe modify my post to match it. Should I import any material to use the onTouchListener? Thanks

Comment: Nope, just use it like you would use the normal onClickListener()

Comment: Action DOWN is an event which is just called once when the user presses it. If you want to increment the 'i' integer then you gotta start some process when Action Down is called and stop that process when Action UP is called. You can't expect the integer to just keep increasing on its own. What's the speed you want it to increase at? Because it might be different in different phones. Think about these factors and maybe try to use Time as a factor to increment your integer.

Comment: Then what's the difference between this and OnClick() if it's going to be called only once? I didn't think of speed but 10/sec should be okay..

Comment: The difference is that in onClick you won't get to know when the user released the button. Now that you know the speed then get access to time and when Action Down is triggered increment your integer by 10 every second. And then when Action Up is called stop incrementing your integer and print the final value of the Integer.

Comment: You are right. Now I see it. Good job and thanks again